# Copy file by c# access denied

Tags: c#, file, copy

I want to copy my application to `D:\\Games` using this code:

```
string path = "D:\\Games";
System.IO.File.Copy(path, Application.ExecutablePath, true);
```

but it gives me this error

> Access to the path 'D:\Games' is denied.

it seams that it haven't access to this path.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is switch the source/target around. Source comes firs.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(Application.ExecutablePath, path, true);
```

Second problem is that string path needs to include the target filename. can't simply copy to a folder without giving the target file name.

Comment: In addition, an example of using the Directory class would probably garner more upvotes, good luck!

Comment: it gives me this error:
The target file "D:\Games" is a directory, not a file.

Comment: You need to change it to D:\Games\some_name

Answer (score 0):

Find the main executable of the program  (bin\Debug) you want to run. Right-click or press and hold on it to open the contextual menu. Then, click or tap on Properties.

In the Properties window, go to the Compatibility tab. At the bottom of the window, check the box next to the “Run this program as an administrator” option, and then click or tap on Apply or OK.